# How do I create a tapered opacity effect around an image in gimp?

Tags: gimp, transparency, borders

I'd like my image to blend into the background gradually around the edges on a web project I'm working on. How do I fade transparency around the edge of an image in gimp?

Comment: This [link](http://wblo.gs/Xo1) has some information that may be helpful.

Comment: cheers, had already found a solution but restrictive interface wouldn't let me post it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This worked best for me in the end.](http://shallowsky.com/linux/quickmask/)

The gist is - create a smaller rectangle and feather the edges. Quick mask and invert the selection then delete leaving you with a faded effect around the remaining centre.

Comment: You should include some of that information in your answer. Links can break/disappear and the answer would become obsolete.